# Pandas cannot load the proper column of the CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I have been facing some problems importing a specific column of a CSV file.I needed to import the Longitude and Latitude Column of the dataset (Fig:1).

But in spyder, the variable explorer is showing the wrong values of the variable (Fig:2). And it seems like that my expected column of values is showing inside the Index column. How do I fix this/ How do I import it?

However, When I click the resize button below on the variable explorer window, the index column expands and show something like Fig: 3

[image]

The code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv',error_bad_lines=False)
X=dataset.loc[:,['latitude','longitude']]
```

Comment: Why are you setting error_bad_lines=False? Also, have you checked that all the rows in the data have the same amount of elements (i.e. columns)? Looks to me you might have some mismatch going on. A check you can try is to import only the first 3 columns and see if they are read properly: read_csv('dataset.csv', usecols=[0:3])

Comment: Used 'error_bad_lines=False' because i have been getting this error:

 "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 62 fields in line 8, saw 65"

your code is saying a syntax error:
X=pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', usecols = [0:3])
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: got the solution. Renamed the column names and BOOYAH!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making an array of column names, and trying to read the csv like so:

```py
colnames = ["latitude", "longitude",...]

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', names=colnames, index_col=0)
# index_col = 0 makes a new index column

# and if you must use error_bad_lines...
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', names=colnames, index_col=0, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set error_bad_lines=False you are telling pandas to not raise an error when an error happens. Your previous error instead was telling you exactly what is going wrong:

```
 "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 62 fields in line 8, saw 65"
```

It means you have lines with more fields than the number of headers, which cause the misalignment when you tell pandas to don't care about that. You should clean your data removing the extra column or import just some specific columns using the headers as the other answer suggests.